# How to save and load settings in a file for an app in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I have been using the configuration object to store and retrieve settings for an app in kivy. The issue is the config object is global and is set for all kivy apps in the system.

What im currently using:

```
from kivy.config import config

...App code

class UserAPP(App);
    def build(self)

    def build_config(self, config)
        config.setdefaults() #multiple key,value pairs
```

Ive searched the kivy documentation for ways to do this, perhaps im searching in the wrong place or for the wrong wrong terms.

My question is: How do i save settings/info to a file which can be loaded upon startup and saved upon shutdown, which is local to each app?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.read('myApp.ini`)
```

then after manipulating `Config`, you can save it to the same file using:

```
Config.write()
```